# C++ inherit a function with different default argument values

Tags: c++, inheritance

I would like to inherit a member function without redefining it, but giving it different default values. What should I do?

```
class Base{
  public:
    void foo(int val){value=val;};
  protected:
    int value;
};

class Derived : public Base{
  public:
    void foo(int val=10);
};

class Derived2 : public Base{
  public:
    void foo(int val=20);
};

void main(){
   Derived a;
   a.foo();//set the value field of a to 10
   Derived2 b;
   b.foo();//set the value field of b to 20
}
```

Comment: @MrSmith42: Call site. That's the usual location anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don’t use defaults, use overloading:

```
class Base{
    public:
        virtual void foo() = 0;

    protected:
        void foo(int val) { value = val; }

    private:
        int value;
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        void foo() override { Base::foo(10); }
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
    public:
        void foo() override { Base::foo(20); }
};
```

`override` modifier is C++11.

Answer (score 3):

In "Effective C++" by Scott Meyers there a chapter called "Never redefine a function's inherited default parameter value". You really shouldn't. You can read the chapter about a very convincing explanations about all the horrors that will happen if you do.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. But you can implement it like this.

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual int getDefaultValue() = 0;
    void foo(){value = getDefaultValue();};
protected:
    int value;
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    int getDefaultValue() {
        return 10;
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Base{
public:
    int getDefaultValue() {
        return 20;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to redefine it — there's no other way to specify a different default argument. But you can keep the implementation trivial by just calling the base version:

```
class Base{
  public:
    void foo(int val){value=val;};
  protected:
    int value;
};

class Derived : public Base{
  public:
    void foo(int val=10) { Base::foo(val); }
};

class Derived2 : public Base{
  public:
    void foo(int val=20) { Base::foo(val); }
};
```